# Is it possible to boot without mounting /home?

Tags: mount, backup, startup, home-directory

I want to backup my `/home` partition on `/dev/sda6` using `partclone`, a command line utility. To do so, I first have to unmount the partition that I want to backup. Most of the time, this is easy, but `/home` is used by so many processes that it can't be unmounted without first killing all those processes.

So, the thing I'm looking for is a way to boot Ubuntu, without mounting `/home`, so I can back up the not-mounted `/dev/sda6` partition. Is that possible?

To be clear, it would be nice if this special boot could be 'one-time-only'. So I'm not looking for ways to change `/etc/fstab` in such way that `/dev/sda6` won't be mounted. That's because that would require me to change `/etc/fstab` twice each time just to make a backup.

I'm aware of the fact that there are other backup solutions available, such as `deja-dup`. I'd like to use `partclone`, though.

Comment: FYI, you gain nothing backing up a /home partition with tools like `partclone` and lose quite a bit.  It is better to just use conventional backup tools like `tar`.

Comment: Could you say why?

Comment: There are several disadvantages to imaging: 1) The problem you have already run into: the partition can not be mounted, 2) you can not exclude certain files ( large iso images you can just download again? ), 3) You can not extract a few files from the image ( accidentally deleted a file? ), 4) you can not restore the image to a smaller partition, even if it is large enough to hold all of the files, and 5) you can not perform incremental backups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You need to boot to single-user mode or recovery mode holding the shift button, after the computer starts. Then you can drop to root shell, so your home folder will be /root and not /home/username. Here you can freely unmount the /home partition, and do anything you would like.
2. Use a live CD/USB to create the backup.

Comment: Especially the first solution sounds great. Will try it out tomorrow.